# Java Wicket - Prevent Form From Creating New Tab When Exception Occurs

Tags: forms, tabs, wicket

I am creating reports using Jasper right now and almost everything goes well. We set it in a way that if the user will preview a report, the report(pdf) will be shown on a new Tab. The problem is if an error occurs, a new Tab would still be opened instead of just showing the Feedback Panel on the original page.

How can the form be setup in such a way that the feedback panel will be shown on the original page instead of the newly opened Tab?

```
Form<?> form = new Form<Void>("form");
form.add(new AttributeAppender("target", Model.of("_blank")));

SubmitLink view= new SubmitLink("view") {
    @Override
    public void onSubmit() {
        //code inside a try-catch to generate the report using Jasper}
};    

CptiDownloadButton download = new CptiDownloadButton("download", new AbstractReadOnlyModel<File>(){
 //CptiDownloadButton extends SubmitLink button and is a modification of Mr Ivaynberg's DownloadLink
};


<form wicket:id="form">
    <a href="#" wicket:id="submit"><input type="button" wicket:message="value:search"/></a>
    <a href="#" wicket:id="download"><input type="button"  wicket:message="value:download"/></a>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who'll answer. ^^

Answer (score 2):

If you do any form submission to a form with `target="_blank"`, the browser will automatically open a new tab to render the response from the form submission. It is the intended behavior, and trying to prevent it is breaking the standard `target="_blank"` behavior. I guess what I'm saying is you should really think whether breaking this standard behavior is something you want to do.

If it is, here's how I would go about it. Warning: ain't gonna be clean.

Use Ajax (`AjaxButton` or `AjaxFormSubmitBehavior`) to submit the form. Since it is done via ajax, the browser will not invoke default form submission behavior, hence not opening a new tab.

Ajax then invokes the form processing. On error, re-render the feedback panel and return. On success append JavaScript to invoke the default form submission on the respective link when the request returns. This will perform standard form submission behavior, hence performing the `target="_blank"`. It will once more validate the form, but then it will proceed to perform the originally intended behavior.

The way you invoke the default form submission on the link you desire can be done in a few different ways and is entirely up to you. As a quick and dirty way you can hide the buttons that you have right now (visually) and perform javascript to click the button. Or you can use a hidden form field to identify which button has been clicked if you don't want ugly hidden clicking behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do a form (Ajax)-submit without target, and then initiate the actual download after checking possible errors.

See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/AJAX+update+and+file+download+in+one+blow for an example with Ajax and an attachment content disposition.

Comment: Hi Mr Sven! Im ok already with the download part. What i just want now is to stop the form from creating new Tab when an exception occurs whether the report is being previewed or downloaded.

Comment: See WiseTree's answer for a better explanation.